# How to make a ScrollView of ListViewBuilder and other widgets?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a ScrollView that contains some widget and also items from ListView Builder. However they should all scroll together (like part of one list) , which seems difficult since ListView Builder has its own scrolling behaviour and will create conflict. How can i resolve this ?

```
 Column tiles = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 14.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0 ),
          child: Row(
          ....// Other Row Widgets I want to scroll 
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getAllTiles,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
             //returns ListView Builder
              }),
        ),
      ],
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the spread operator

````
ListView(
     children: [
       DrawerHeader(...),
       ..._buildUserGroups(context),
       ListTile(...)
     ],
   ),```
Note: this is available only in Dart>2.2
````